Databases bidirectional synchronization
I would like to synchronize two databases bidirectionally, i.e. from old database to new and from new to old. I can use Debezium to achieve this goal. But what are my options to avoid infinite loops, i.e. situation when insert to old database triggers insert to new database and this one triggers insert to old database and so on?
I know I can enrich both old and new database with additional columns that store some synchronization GUID. But is there any way to avoid modifying old database that would still prevent infinite loops?
My scenario is such that there will be two databases, old and new - and also two sets of applications, old applications writing to old database and new applications writing to new database. Gradually, old applications will be migrated to new applications and new schema so that ultimately old database and applications can be abandoned.
So far I have configured Debezium to watch database changes in both databases and small application that listens to the events created by Debezium and saves them to proper database. And now I need to avoid infinite loops.

I think your question is based on a wrong assumption that it is the sync functionality that needs to avoid circular changes. I think your apps must be designed the way that a modification will not result in another modification that may cause a circular modification in another app. With two way sync the main risk is conflicting modifications and you need to develop the strategy to handle those.

Standard MySQL replication achieves this by noting the server-id in each binary log event. Replication will not execute an event that has the same server-id as the instance executing. So if you have two instances in bidirectional replication,  it avoids infinite loops. I don't know Debezium well enough, does it give you access to the server-id in the events?

Also, why are you using Debezium when standard MySQL replication can already do what you want?

@BillKarwin I suspect standard MySQL replication won't be enough because old and new schemas will be different so transformations in application that reads Debezium events would be required. I've searched by "debezium server-id" and see that it should be possible to read MySQL server id from 'source' field name. But I don't see how that would prevent infinite loops because that won't distinguish between change in new server arriving from my small application that reads Debezium events and saves to other schema and changes coming from real applications using new schema. And vice versa.

I see what you're saying. If you're transforming the data, then it won't be the same event, it'll be a new event, even if it is logically based on another original event. I don't think your task is easy to solve. It took MySQL 20 years to develop GTID's, and that's for replicating events with no transformations.

@BillKarwin I wonder if that would be possible to somehow base it on the user that is making changes, i.e. create special user that will save from my connector application to the destination database and ignore in my connector application those events that are done by this user. But it depends on whether it is possible to add information about user making changes to MySQL binlogs and if Debezium can read this information. Do you know?

I have not used Debezium.

@BillKarwin But is it possible to save information about user making changes to MySQL binlogs? Or alternatively, make sure that SQL commands comments are preserved (I can make special comment in events coming from connector application)? If not possible out of the box, is there any way to enhance MySQL by writing some plugin? Thanks!

I do know for a fact that binlog events do not contain user information. It's irrelevant on the replica, because the thread that executes changes on the replica bypasses permissions. It is assumed that permissions were checked at the time they were executed on the source instance, so any event written in the binlogs was by definition permitted.

I don't know of any plugin to modify how binlogs are written, so it would require custom code in the mysql server itself. But you'll find that it's not so clear which user is responsible for a given change, because some changes are executed by views or stored routines and these can act as either the caller or the definer.
